# Input to console in Xcode 4

Tags: console, gdb, xcode4

I upgraded to Xcode 4 recently. Love the IB integration; hate pretty much everything else.

Anyway, maybe it's just me going crazy, but I can't seem to be able to input anything into the GDB command line (can you even open the console other then as the output window or through the Log navigator??).

Anybody has a solution? Hoping it's just me being stupid here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To view output & type commands for GDB, make sure the output window is open.

In the top-right of Xcode 4 you have 3 groups of buttons labeled 'Editor', 'View' and 'Organiser'. Make sure the middle botton of the 'View' group is enabled.

On the bottom, the output window should now be visible. To the top-right of that output panel, there are 3 visibility toggle buttons. Make sure either the middle one (watch window + output console) or the right one (just the console) is selected.

Hope this helps.