# Set malloc_error_break in Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How do I set a malloc_error_break in Xcode4? Also, I seem to be getting this error `malloc: *** error for object 0x4d80814: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.`

Is there anyway I can check what object 0x4d80814 is? It doesn't show up in the variables list in the debugger.

Comment: It doesn't show up in the debugger because it has been deallocated and probably referenced internally from Apple's code.  I would suggest using Analyzer to find any obvious inconsistencies in your memory management.

Comment: Chances are you're modifying an already-deallocated object, and `malloc` is detecting it some time later.  You're likely to pinpoint the location of the error if you profile it and use the Zombies instrument.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I think this is how its done.

- Click on the breakpoints navigator (looks like a sign post) on the top of the left bar on
  XCode 4.
- On the bottom left hand corner there is a plus sign. Click on it.
- Add Symbolic Breakpoint and set malloc_error_break as the symbol.
- Click the next breakpoint button ( it looks like |> ) and is on the bottom panel. It will take you to the line that is causing the error.

Usually it is caused by objects being created as subobjects of other objects that don't exist yet (ie SKPhysicsBody being created before its spritenode exists)

Comment: Can you provide me more details for this point: Click the next breakpoint button ( it looks like |> ) and is on the bottom panel. It will take you to the line that is causing the error. 
I am using xcode 8 and I didn't find |> this kind of symbol

Answer (score 14):

This is what the breakpoints button looks like:

[image]

And this is the plus sign at the bottom left hand corner:

[image]

Man, it took me a while to find both of them!

Comment: Come on, man. For people who have always bee setting their breakpoints via mouse/keyboard shortcut this is new stuff. Not everyone knows this.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do it directly through the gdb command window.

```
break malloc_error_break
```

or in lldb:

```
breakpoint set -n malloc_error_break
```

To open the debugger command window in XCode 4, click the middle button above "View" in the top right corner, then click the middle button in the top right corner of the bottom debugging pane that just opened. See also [Input to console in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558811/input-to-console-in-xcode-4)

Comment: note that this is for gdb but the default debugger is usually lldb, which has a different syntax