# malloc_error_break how it works

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, compiler-errors, xcode5

I got an errors like this: `malloc: *** error for object 0x10ec5750: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Project(4017,0xb0115000) malloc: *** error for object 0x1179fe90: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`. I read that i should to use malloc_error_break. I follow to Breakpoint Navigator -> (plus in bottom) add a new breakpoint-> add Symbolic Breakpoint. Then i fill in the form.`Symbol: malloc_error_break  Module: libSystem.B.dylib` Run project and i get the same error. Maybe i set `malloc_error_break` incorrect? And how it should be looks like correct? How it works? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set malloc\_error\_break in Xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969407/set-malloc-error-break-in-xcode-4)

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the Module, just the Symbol should suffice

Comment: I read it already. it doesn't help. I got nothing

Comment: when i delete Module field I run project and i get ` libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_error_break: 0x20dd7f9: push %ebp` And 7 more addresses. What should i do with it? How to solve the problem????

Comment: If you look in the navigator to the left, you should see the stack trace; the top one will be `0 malloc_error_break`. Looking down the trace, any row that's black (not gray) is your code.

Comment: No Not any black row